# What processes should I follow and what programs should I use to transfer my HD data to an SSD?

Tags: ssd, transfer, clonezilla

I'm going to be swapping my HD for an SSD and want to first be able to transfer all of the HD's content to the SSD. For Windows, there's Macrium Reflect. I did some research and Clonezilla seems to be the alternative for Ubuntu but I feel insecure even with its use (through a bootable USB).

I was wondering if Clonezilla is really the way to go and how to use it properly for that means, or if there's an easy alternative.

Comment: clonezilla is a good choice...

Answer (score 0):

From a bootable Linux USB I have been, successfully, using `dd` for both Windows and Linux.  Since `dd` will make a block by block copy, it will literally mirror the disk.  But you have to be **extremely careful** to make the copy from the right source into the desired destination, **or you can end up with two empty disks**.

Also, make sure that the disks are:

1. the same size; or
2. destination disk is bigger than the source disk; or
3. that the amount of data on the source disk is less than the total amount of available space on the destination.

You can identify the disks using the `dmesg` command, like so:

```bsh
dmesg | grep sd
```

Which will give the following output, and allow to identify the disks by it's size and other information that are presented:

```bsh
[300469.247685] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 15633408 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 GB/7.45 GiB)
[300469.248431] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[300469.248441] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[300469.248737] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[300469.250327] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[300469.280515]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[300469.282572] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[300474.681838] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[300474.683284] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 31260672 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[300474.684127] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[300474.684136] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[300474.684398] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[300474.723553]  sdc: sdc1
[300474.726500] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Another way of identifying the disks is using the `lsblk` command:

```bsh
lsblk -o NAME,MODEL,SIZE -d
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
NAME MODEL                       SIZE
sda  Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_250GB 232,9G
sdb  Cruzer_Blade                7,5G
sdc  Cruzer_Blade               14,9G
```

The syntax to the copy is:

```bsh
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 status=progress
```

Where:

**if=/dev/sda1** is the source disk

**of=/dev/sdb1** is the destination disk

**status=progress** will show the progress of the copy

The output will be something like this:

```
cayenne :: ~/tmp/x » dd if=src.iso of=dst.iso status=progress
40960+0 records in
40960+0 records out
20971520 bytes (21 MB, 20 MiB) copied, 0,325608 s, 64,4 MB/s
```

Again, be really careful as to the order of the disks.  If the disks are of different sizes, you may adjust the partitions on the destination disk using `gparted`.